# aSmack muc.getMembers() Forbidden (403) OPENFIRE

Tags: java, android, openfire, smack, asmack

I would like to allow any chat room member to get a list of all of the members. Currently, only users who are moderators may do so. I cannot seem to find where I need to set / change the user privileges to allow for this.

If logged in as a moderator the following code works:

```
 try {
                Collection<Affiliate> members = muc.getMembers();
                System.out.println(members.size());
            } catch(XMPPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

If logged in as a normal member, the above code throws a Forbidden 403 error.

```
 06-25 19:53:51.198: W/System.err(12943): forbidden(403)
 06-25 19:53:51.208: W/System.err(12943):   at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.getAffiliatesByAdmin(MultiUserChat.java:1743)
 06-25 19:53:51.208: W/System.err(12943):   at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.getMembers(MultiUserChat.java:1657)
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that a [MUC Member](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#roles-default) is not the same of an entity that joined the room. I guess you want a list of all entities currently in the MUC, correct?

Comment: Hi @Flow, no I would like a list of all MUC members, or a list of all entities to ever be in the MUC. I thought I could achieve the later by registering each new participant as a member when they join, although the above problem ensued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1) Make sure the user associated with the session used to instantiate the MulitUserChat instance (muc) has sufficient room privileges to get the members list (I think, but am not sure, that the user needs admin privileges for the room)

2) If 1 is sufficiently handled make sure you are calling SmackAndroid.init(Context context)

hope this helps!

-- with regard to your last comment --

I apologize from losing sight of the original question. You are correct, both functions can only be called by an admin user. There is no way (that I am aware of) to have a member gain admin privileges without the consent of an admin user. After a bit more consideration, I concluded that this is a poor solution anyway as granting admin privileges to all users compromises the security of your chat room. Fortunately, there is a better solution(it is a bit more involved):

You can create a plugin (http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html) that uses the botz library (http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1130#comment-5601). Upon creation of a muc room grant the bot admin privileges to the room. When a user needs to pull down the members list, the user should send the query to the bot, the bot should query the room and relay the results to the user. This design preserves the security of your room and, aside from being fun, botz can be useful beyond this purpose. -- I hope this helps

Comment: hey @Scott- thank you so much for answering! is there a way to automate the admin privileges process? For example, I currently have it set up so that new users can become members by                            Form registrationForm = muc.getRegistrationForm();                  Form answerForm = registrationForm.createAnswerForm(); answerForm.setAnswer("muc#register_first", "name");              answerForm.setAnswer("muc#register_roomnick", USERNAME) muc.sendRegistrationForm(answerForm);

Comment: Im not sure if this is what you are asking but you can grant any user or collection of users admin privileges with the MulitUserChat instance by calling instance.grantAdmin(String jid) or instnace.grantAdmin(Collection<String> jids). The same thing can be done to grant Moderator privileges with instance.grantModerator(String nickName) and instance.grantModerator(Collection<String> nicknames) -- let me know  if this is not what you are looking for

Comment: I believe both of those methods can only be called by an admin user. What I am looking for is a way for ANY user to be able to either a) get a members list or b) get a list of every person to ever use the chatroom. Either a) or b) should be able to be done autonomously. If there is a way to have users automatically gain admin privileges either by form submission or some setting on Openfire I am all ears!

Comment: Edited my answer because the response was too long for a comment.

Comment: that solution looks very promising, thank you! I really appreciate the time you spent digging into this.